# NEPacketTunnelProvider Why I am getting packets from this IP 17.130.21.5:443

Tags: ios, iphone, vpn, tunnel, networkextension

For creating NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings settings I am using the bellow code.

In this code I am only adding `"8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1"` in IPV4 includedRoutes  and ,`"2001:4860:4860::8888"` IPV6 includedRoutes. excludedRoutes are default.

But I am getting some packets from `17.130.21.5:443` this IP.

```
- (NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings *)createTunnelSettings {
    NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings *settings = [[NEPacketTunnelNetworkSettings alloc] initWithTunnelRemoteAddress:@"127.1.1.1"];
    NEIPv4Settings *ipv4 = [[NEIPv4Settings alloc]
                            initWithAddresses:@[@"172.16.209.2"]
                            subnetMasks:@[@"255.255.255.252"]];

    NEIPv6Settings *ipv6 = [[NEIPv6Settings alloc]
                            initWithAddresses:@[@"fd12:1:1:1::2"]
                            networkPrefixLengths:@[ @(64)]];


    NEDNSSettings * dns = [[NEDNSSettings alloc] initWithServers: [@"8.8.8.8", @"1.1.1.1",@"2001:4860:4860::8888"]];
    NSMutableArray* ipv4IncludedRoutes = [NSMutableArray new];


    [ipv4IncludedRoutes addObject:[[NEIPv4Route alloc] initWithDestinationAddress:@"8.8.8.8"
                                                                       subnetMask:@"255.255.255.255"]];
    [ipv4IncludedRoutes addObject:[[NEIPv4Route alloc] initWithDestinationAddress:@"1.1.1.1"
                                                                       subnetMask:@"255.255.255.255"]];

    NSMutableArray* ipv6IncludedRoutes = [NSMutableArray new];
    [ipv6IncludedRoutes addObject:[[NEIPv6Route alloc] initWithDestinationAddress:@"2001:4860:4860::8888"
                                                              networkPrefixLength: @(128)]];

    ipv4.includedRoutes = ipv4IncludedRoutes;
    ipv6.includedRoutes = ipv6IncludedRoutes;

    ipv4.excludedRoutes = @[[NEIPv4Route defaultRoute]];
    ipv6.excludedRoutes = @[[NEIPv6Route defaultRoute]];

    dns.matchDomains = @[ @"" ];
    settings.DNSSettings = dns;

    if(ipv4Available) {
        settings.IPv4Settings = ipv4;
    }

    if(ipv6Available) {
        settings.IPv6Settings = ipv6;

    }
}
return settings;

}
```

Comment: Hi Imran, I'm trying  to use VPN tunnel and local server in networkExtension but not able to move ahead as, i'm lost in few things like where to start the server and how to redirect the packets back to the network. Also which IPAddress is this one "172.16.209.2", I mean at my end which one should i use, also which server to be used in the VPN configuration as i'm using a local server. If you can help me a little bit with this it would be great.

Comment: "172.16.209.2" address can be any private IP.

Where to start the server?

I did not have any real server running. I configured the VPN to use a fake server with any Local IP address like "127.1.1.1", this fake server will intercept the outgoing network traffic... once i got the packets, I rout them to their actual destination.

Comment: Last thing can you share some code how you route the packets to network, inn my case when i'm connected to VPN tunnel, network is not working in the Phone.